# Are modules in nancyfx really created on each request?

Tags: nancy

I have created a simple self hosted Nancy site with a single module in a console project. When testing it out I noticed that the module constructor is called on each request. This puzzles me because the ctor is also where routes are registered. That does not make sense to me and I must be missing something. So are module constructors called on each request and are all routes thus re-registered on each request?

Comment: I was also concerned about this. Less about routes, and more about dependencies that might be expensive to create. So I setup static properties to cache the dependencies between constructions. Then a bunch of my tests failed, because the first test's bootstrapper was being used for all subsequent tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sort of - Nancy will construct all modules at startup, register all their routes and build the routing Tree. For each request it will then figure out which Module it needs and construct it using the request container, so request scoped dependencies have the correct lifetime, then executes the relevant action. The routes are not "registered" every request, they are just stored in a collection in the module and the engine executes the correct one.

Comment: But all routes are then restored in a DynamicDictionary on each request event though they are not needed (because we know what route match the request) ? is yes then this seems odd to do work on a request that is not needed. Is there a better way to register routes than in the ctor so that as little as possible is done on each request ?

Comment: also, it seems to be wise not to have to many routes in a module then, but instead have more modeules with fewer routes each ?

Comment: It makes very little difference.. we did load testing with millions of modules and thousands of routes in each module. But in general we "normally" see people breaking down their modules into functional areas/resources, rather than clubbing things together.

Comment: @StevenRobbins it's not the performance but that design choice that is very disturbing for me. Would it hurt if the registrations are done in a separate `virtual void RegisterRoutes()` method? It will get called from Nancy at startup while the module would still be created for each request without any additional (as minimal as it can be) overhead. It is not a breaking change, too, so old modules will still work.

Comment: @ceco – no, that wouldn't work, because the registrations tie the handling of requests to a specific NancyModule instance. That means that the handlers found during startup when discovering & registering routes are tied specifically to the throwaway instance used for that discovery. To make matters worse, the use of anonymous functions/lambda expressions means that, under the hood, a separate generated class is used to hold lexical scope – the methods might not even be part of the module type directly. There's no way around it; to execute on the right instance, the constructor must be re-run.

Comment: Strongly agree with @ceco that it is an [astonishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) pattern that Nancy has followed. Ordinary mortals would guess that, if the endpoint->instance binding is done on startup, then that is the instance that will be (re)used for every call bound to that endpoint. Would love to understand better why it can't/shouldn't be that way, and whether I have any options to configure my (stateless!) modules to be instantiated just once and shared (NB this is about clarity of my code, not performance).